# "Este programa no funciona" ¿Dar pistas o no decir nada?

Tags: discusión

De vez en cuando<sup>1</sup> salen preguntas de "esto no funciona" que, aunque proporcionan detalles de comportamiento esperado y comportamiento obtenido, no centran la pregunta en un código concreto.

A veces la cuestión es que se está usando un método, o una API mal y son preguntas que entiendo que la gente haga; es algo que depurando difícilmente saldrá sin conocer la respuesta. Otras veces es simplemente que ha habido un error de programación (algo no inicializado, o una condición no comprobada) y la cuestión es que el OP no se ha tomado la molestia de seguir la ejecución de su programa con un depurador o similar.

Las preguntas del primer tipo las contesto (si sé la solución, claro), las del segundo soy mucho más reacio (quizás con alguien que evidentemente está justo empezando a programar, pero nada más) porque permite a la gente ignorar como depurar sus programas.

Pero para cuando he decidido si una pregunta es de un tipo o del otro, si es del segundo tipo normalmente ya he encontrado la solución. Dando por sentado que no voy a responder a la pregunta, suelo dejar una indicación<sup>2</sup> a ver si, limitando el alcance, el OP se anima a depurar por su cuenta.

Pero me preguntaba si a la gente le puede parecer algo pretencioso<sup>3</sup> esta costumbre mía, y si se considera mejor no dar "pistas"<sup>4</sup>.

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Preferiría haber evitado señalar a nadie en concreto, pero dado que se me ha pedido referir a un ejemplo, está [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133447/recorrer-arrayliststring-y-comparar-subcadenas-si-son-iguales-o-similares)

---

<sup>1</sup>Bueno, vale, a menudo.

<sup>2</sup>Del tipo "¿Es curioso que este valor que imprimes solo se incremente, no? ¿Por qué será?"

<sup>3</sup>"Sé la respuesta y no te la voy a decir."

<sup>4</sup>Que conste que no he dicho que si sale que es pretencioso, yo vaya dejar de hacerlo :-P

Comment: Podrías editar e incluir alguna pregunta de ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Yo personalmente suelo en esos casos intentar dar pistas sobre la manera de solucionar el problema,o añado algún enlace que explique el problema mas en profundidad.

No considero que sea una cuestión de ser pretencioso, sino que por un lado en el sitio se pide haber realizado previamente un esfuerzo de investigación y de tratar de resolver el problema, y por otro poner una solución para que el OP simplemente copie y pegue sin entender lo que hace no considero que sea ayudarle a futuro.